# Algorithm to find smallest array from a list of n arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I need to find out smallest array from a list of `n` arrays in JavaScript. What will be the best algorithm for this?

```
var a = [1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7, 3, 5, 9, 0],
    b = [2, 4, 7, 5, 1, 2, 8],
    c = [5, 3, 7, 6];

function doSomething() {
  // arguments
}
```

Here the result should be `c`. That is `[5, 3, 7, 6]`

Note: The number of arrays is not defined, there may be 10s or 100s of array passed to the function using `fn.call`

Comment: What do you mean by 'smallest'? minimum number of elements or minimum of sum of elements?

Comment: Arrays have a `.length` property.

Comment: Test them one by one. You may want an array of arrays as input for `doSomething`.

Comment: An algorithm can use built-in functions. What you mean is this is homework and your teacher told you not to use built-in functions, right?

Comment: @Larabone - you're lucky you sneaked this homework question through, usually they're spotted and you wont get a fully working answer. Next time, do your own homework, you learn nothing by getting random people off the internet to do it for you. Im deleting my answer. I hope others do the same.

Comment: @Larabone - I'll tell you what, give me the email address of your teacher, Ill ask them if they're happy me doing (or even starting) your homework for you, and if they agree ill re-instate my answer. I dont think they will be. Do your own homewoork.

Comment: This question is a homework and OP made no effort to solve it.

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks, next time I will try my best. But after getting the result, can I ask in the community is it the right optimized way or not?

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved by using the following implementation.

```
function doSomething(){
    var Result = a;
    if ( b.length < Result.length )
        Result = b;
    if ( c.length < Result.length )
        Result = c;
    return Result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrays = [
    [1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 7, 3, 5, 9, 0],
    [2, 4, 7, 5, 1, 2, 8],
    [5, 3, 7, 6],
]

function smallestArray(arrays) {
  var min = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
  var smallest;

  for(var l = arrays.length-1; l >= 0; l--) {
    var length = arrays[l].length;
    if (length < min) {
      min = length;
      smallest = arrays[l];
    }
  }

  return smallest;
}

smallestArray(arrays)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Put them in an array
var arr = [a,b,c];
// Sort it
arr.sort(function (list1,list2){
    // compare lists by lengths
    return list1.length - list2.length;
});
// take the first one.
var shortest = arr[0];
```

Comment: Sorting is a bit overkill here.

Comment: Sort is actually O(n*log n)

Comment: You could iterate the list, and compare manually, keeping the minimum each time. But `sort` is going to be very fast even for very large arrays.